# Writing C++ DLL from a C-defined Interface

Tags: c++, c, dll

I was given a C header file that acts as an interface for writing a DLL. That DLL is then read dynamically by an executable for testing. I'm new to the world of DLL creation and I'm struggling to get the executable to recognize my DLL as having the entry points it expects. Unfortunately, the executable does not tell me *why* my DLL is invalid. I've used to tool to make sure I've exported my functions with the correct names, but I'm guessing something about my function signatures signatures makes them incompatible. I've also made sure I'm building x64 as instructed in a README.

> C Interface Header

```
#include <stdint.h>
#pragma pack(push, 1)

struct Point
{
    int8_t id;
    int32_t rank;
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct Rect
{
    float lx;
    float ly;
    float hx;
    float hy;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

struct SearchContext;

typedef SearchContext* (__stdcall* T_create)(const Point* points_begin, const Point* points_end);

typedef int32_t (__stdcall* T_search)(SearchContext* sc, const Rect rect, const int32_t count, Point* out_points);

typedef SearchContext* (__stdcall* T_destroy)(SearchContext* sc);
```

> My C++ Header

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
#pragma pack(push, 1)

struct Point
{
    int8_t id;
    int32_t rank;
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct Rect
{
    float lx;
    float ly;
    float hx;
    float hy;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

struct SearchContext
{
    float value;
    float minCoverage, maxCoverage;
    SearchContext* leftTree;
    SearchContext* rightTree;
    SearchContext* yTree;
    Point* point;
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) SearchContext* create(const Point* points_begin, const Point* points_end);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int32_t search(SearchContext * sc, const Rect rect, const int32_t count, Point * out_points);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) SearchContext* destroy(SearchContext * sc);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You probably need to wrap your `struct` definitions in `extern "C"` as well.

Comment: You might want to look at your dll exports with a viewer such as this one: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html to make sure you're exporting what you think you are.

Comment: @MarkRansom what is the effect of the struct definition being extern "C" ? I thought there'd be no effect there.

Comment: The `C` header doesn't export any functions - so we have the `C++` but don't have the `C` for reference.  Note the `C` header file only `typedef`s no exported functions are actually defined.

Comment: @Jeffrey C++ uses mangled names, C does not.

Comment: @MarkRansom what I mean is: Are the struct name themselves mangled ?

Comment: @Jeffrey I'm not sure, but certainly the functions that take them as parameters will be.

Comment: @bruceg I already have and everything checks out.

Comment: @RichardCritten I don't believe it's supposed to. I think it just gives the signatures it expects.

Comment: Please add a specific example of an error message.  Is coming from the linker (when you build the executable) or from the system when you try to start your application?  Is your executable linked against the DLL's import library file or is it calling LoadLibrary to load it explicitly?

Comment: So how do the `C` functions get exported?  We don't even know if the names of the exported function are correct.  Also, how are they imported by name or by ordinal?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Unfortunately the executable gives a custom fail message (without description) and I wasn't given its source, so I don't know how it is being read. Though my guess is that it's the latter because it loads on runtime.

Comment: @RichardCritten By name. I have a reference DLL (which does work with the executable) that I confirmed the function names with. The C header was just given as a outline for creating the DLL in whatever language I wanted, so it's not designed to export anything.